# In snowflake error while creating warehouse using RESOURCE_MONITOR with sysadmin role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, warehouse

In snowflake, we are creating a warehouse but when we create a warehouse with resource_moniter clause(it was created by accountadmin ) by sysadmin role it gives access level error. we have given all privileges to sysadmin on this resource monitor but it doesn't work.

can someone help in the creation of a warehouse without using "accountadmin" role?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE WAREHOUSE privilege as listed here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html

must be granted by the accountadmin role to any other role which is being used for this operation.

By default sysadmin role would have this privilege, if not, then grant the privilege as accountadmin and use the sysadmin role to run the create operation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create a warehouse with Resource Monitor unless you use the accountadmin role (even if you change the ownership of the resource monitor). Please note that, when you assign a resource monitor to a warehouse, you do not only affect the warehouse, you also affect the resource monitor because it might be shared by other users.

You need to create the warehouse, and then assign the resource monitor to the warehouse using the accountadmin role.